# SQL limit query optimization with condition and sort

Tags: mysql, optimization

There's a SQL:

```sql
select * from table where A=cid order by B desc, C desc limit lower_bound, 10;
```

Every column has had their indexes.

When the `lower_bound` is big, it takes a long time to query. Because there are a billion of records in the table, and some of `cid` has more than 10 million records.

I try to add a union index `(A, B, C)`. My DB is based on MySQL, but it don't support union index.

Are there any solutions to optimize this query?

Comment: In fact, an index on `(A, B, C)` might help here.  Are you saying you couldn't create this index?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support

Comment: Where did you come up with the term "union index"??  And what gives you the idea that such a composite index is not supported?

Comment: There is a problem with a large lower bound -- The table (or index) will need to be scanned past that many rows before delivering the desired 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `Composite Index` as below:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name(A,B,C);
```

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> The index can also be used even if the `ORDER BY` does not match the index exactly, as long as all of the unused portions of the index and all the extra `ORDER BY` columns are constants in the `WHERE` clause.

[**MySQL Composite Index**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/#:~:targetText=MySQL%20allows%20you%20to%20create,two%20columns%2C%20and%20so%20on.)

Comment: The OP already appears to have tried this.  Also, you gave no explanation on why this should help.

Comment: I doubt if the OP actually tried this.  Perhaps he tried to do something like "CREATE UNION INDEX(a,b,c)", which is bogus.